# Finding the culprit behind "Another program on your computer would like to modify Firefox with the following add-on"

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I booted my Win 10 today and started Firefox. All of a sudden I got the "warning" in the title. The add-on was **Search and New Tab by Yahoo**. I looked in my installed applications and right at the bottom I had a newly installed application called Yahoo Search Set. Needless to say I didn't install it.

The problem with the message above is that it doesn't provide enough information about who's trying to install the add-on. Yes, in this case I got it right but what are the chances of an adware or other malicious piece of software (I view Yahoo Search Set as well as the Firefox add-on as such since it installed without me saying so) announcing itself in a clear way?

Is there a way to find who is trying to add something new to Firefox (or any other mainstream browser for that matter)?

Comment: You can always try to infer the program that carried the malware using the install date.

Comment: Unless other software was installed after the malware installed itself, which will make things more difficult. I was looking of a more straight forward method without the need to manually check the list of installed software.

Comment: ? Windows records the install date of all programs. Unless something else was installed on the same day, you’ll be able to narrow down the search a lot.

Comment: "Unless something else was installed on the same day" I'm looking for a solution that is independent from the time the malware installed itself, how it's called etc. (basically everything that involves manual search no matter how small the effort is).

Comment: You may try [AdwCleaner](https://www.malwarebytes.com/adwcleaner/) from Malwarebytes.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet real money that it came from [installing Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/yahoo.xml).

If that's not the case, you might also want to check for the presence of [Spigot](https://www.wintips.org/remove-spigot-search-settings/) on your machine.